# What happens to the Riemann-Stieltjes integral when the integrator has jumps?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The Riemann-Stieltjes integral of a real-valued function $f$ of a real variable on the interval $[a, b]$ with respect to another real-to-real function $g$ is denoted by
\begin{equation*}
\int_{x=a}^b f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x)
\end{equation*}
Its definition uses a sequence of partitions $P$ of the interval $[a, b]$
\begin{equation*}
P=\left\{a=x_0<x_1<\cdots<x_n=b\right\}
\end{equation*}
The integral, then, is defined to be the limit, as the mesh (the length of the longest subinterval) of the partitions approaches 0 , of the approximating sum
\begin{equation*}
S(P, f, g)=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} f\left(c_i\right)\left[g\left(x_{i+1}\right)-g\left(x_i\right)\right]
\end{equation*}
where $c_i$ is in the $i$-th subinterval $\left[x_i ; x_{i+1}\right]$. The two functions $f$ and $g$ are respectively called the integrand and the integrator. Typically $g$ is taken to be monotone (or at least of bounded variation) and right-semicontinuous (however this last is essentially convention).

Suppose that the integrator $g$ is of bounded variation with a jump at $y\in[a,b]$. Then I imagine that

\begin{equation*}
\int_{a}^b f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x)= \int_{a}^c f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x) + \int_{c}^b f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x) + f(y) \Delta g(y).
\end{equation*}

First question: if $f$ also jumps at $y$, should we take the left limit or the right limit in $f(y) \Delta g(y)$ for $f$?

Now suppose that $g$ has infinitely many jumps in $[a,b]$. Then if the above holds, $\int_{a}^b f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x)$ should be equal to a series of integrals, each over a subinterval of continuity of $g$, plus $f(y_i)\Delta g(y_i)$, where $y_i$ are the points where the jumps happen.

Second question: How can we be sure of the convergence of that series?

Comment: The Riemann-Stieltjes integral $\int_{a}^b f(x) \mathrm{d} g(x)$ may *not exist* if $f$ and $g$ have a common point of discontinuity.